# Inserting elements into a double linked list python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code the insert function. This is what I have so far but it's only outputting [15]. I'm mainly confused with what the node in the if and elif statements in the insert function are referring to.

```
class Container:
    class node:
        def __init__( self, value, nextNode, prevNode ):
            self.value = value
            self.next = nextNode
            self.prev = prevNode

    def __init__( self ):           
        self.top = self.last = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__( self ):
        return self.size

    def _locate( self, val ):
        currentNode=self.top
        while True:
            if currentNode is None:
                return None, False
            # code the rest of _locate. Make a complete case analysis
            elif currentNode.value == val:
                return currentNode, True
            elif currentNode.value>val:
                return currentNode, False
            elif currentNode.next == None:
                return None, False
            else:
                currentNode = currentNode.next


    #Code the three functions     
    def find( self, val ): 
        temp = val 
        if self._locate(temp) is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def insert( self, val ):
        #use _locate. If found=True, do nothing
        # If found=False and node is not None,
        #   then insert a new node just before the returned node
        # If found=False and node is None
        #   then insert a new node at the last pointer
        # And change size
        # Complete the function code in the four cases below

        node, found = self._locate(val) 

        if found==False:

            newNode = self.node(val, None, None)

            if node is not None and node.prev is not None:
                newNode.next = newNode

            elif node is not None and node.prev is None:
                newNode.next = newNode

            elif node is None and self.last is not None:
                self.prev = self.top
                selt.top = self.top.next
            elif node is None and self.last is None:
                self.top = newNode

    def delete( self, val ):
        # Use _locate again.
        # Delete the returned node if found is True
        #    in the four cases below
        node, found = self._locate(val)
        '''
        if found:
            if node.prev is not None and node.next is not None:
                node.prev = node.next #trying to connect node.prev pointer to node.next pointer
            elif node.prev is not None and node.next is None:
                self.last = node.prev #make the previous node the last node
            elif node.prev is None and node.next is not None:
                self.top = node.next #current node is first node, change it so next node is the new first node
            elif node.prev is None and node.next is None:
                self.size = 0 #there's only one node in list, change the size so now there's zero
                '''



#For code check
c = Container()
c.insert(10)
c.insert(4)
c.insert(2)
c.insert(15)
c.delete(4)
c.insert(8)
c.insert(9)
c.delete(10)
check=[]
pointer = c.top

while pointer is not None:
   check.append(pointer.value)
   pointer = pointer.next
print(check)
print(c.find(8), c.find(10))
# The output should be
#   [2, 8, 9, 15]
#   True False
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation errors, so we can reproduce the problem.  What debugging have you done so far?  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Off topic, but `find` will always return `False`, because you are checking if the return value of `_locate` (which always returns a tuple) is the object `True`.

Answer (score 0):

- You called this 'the insert function' with no mention of sorting while being inserted but your expected output showed it as a sorted output. I have gone with a plain insertion (i.e. without sorting).
- As @chepner mentioned your find function makes a call to 'locate' which returns a tuple but you are comparing this tuple to a single value (i.e. True or False)

  ```
  class Container_insert_notSorted:

      class node:
          def __init__( self, value, nextNode, prevNode ):
              self.value = value
              self.next = nextNode
              self.prev = prevNode

      def __init__( self ):           
          self.top = self.last = None
          self.size = 0

      def __len__( self ):
          return self.size

      def _locate( self, val ):
          currentNode=self.top
          while True:
              if currentNode is None:
                  return None, False
              elif currentNode.value == val:
                  return currentNode, True
              elif currentNode.next == None:
                  return None, False
              else:
                  currentNode = currentNode.next

          return None, False


      #Code the three functions     
      def find( self, val ): 
          node, found = self._locate(val)
          return found


      def insert( self, val ):
          newNode = self.node(val, None, None)

          if self.last is None:
              self.top = newNode
              self.last = newNode

          else:
              node, found = self._locate(self.last.value)
              if found:
                  newNode.prev = node.value
                  node.next = newNode
                  self.last = newNode
  ```

The logic is

1. First time you run insert, create a new node whose prev and next pointers are null; set self.top to the new node; set self.last to the new node.
2. Subsequent runs

   - Create a new node
   - locate your last node (i.e. locate self.last.value) = node
   - node.next should point to this new node you just created
   - then overwrite lastnode so that it now points to this new node